# SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE performance

Tags: mysql, performance, select, select-into-outfile

I am trying to optimize the export process of a query.
I have the following tables (I omit some irrelevant fields):

```
CREATE TABLE _termsofuse (
    ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, TTC_ART_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    TTC_TYP_ID int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    TERM_OF_USE_NAME varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    TERM_OF_USE_VALUE varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=185905671 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE vehicle (
  ID mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TTC_TYP_ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY TTC_TYP_ID_UNIQUE (TTC_TYP_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44793 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE part (
  ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TTC_ART_ID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  UNIQUE KEY TTC_ART_ID_UNIQUE (TTC_ART_ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3732260 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE term_of_use_name (
  ID smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ID_Lang tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID, ID_Lang),
  UNIQUE KEY Name_Lang_UNIQUE (Name, ID_Lang),
  KEY fk_term_of_use_name_lang_id_lang_idx (ID_Lang),
  CONSTRAINT fk_term_of_use_name_lang_id_lang FOREIGN KEY (ID_Lang) 
  REFERENCES  lang (ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=732 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE term_of_use_value (
  ID mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ID_Lang tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  Value varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID,ID_Lang),
  UNIQUE KEY Value_Lang_UNIQUE (Value,ID_Lang),
  KEY fk_term_of_use_value_lang_id_lang_idx (ID_Lang),
  CONSTRAINT fk_term_of_use_value_lang_id_lang FOREIGN KEY (ID_Lang) 
  REFERENCES lang (ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=887502 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I try to select some columns to a csv file. Afterwards i will import the file to a database table, but I suspect this should not take too much time.
My Select statement is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vehicle.ID, part.ID, term_of_use_name.ID, term_of_use_value.ID FROM _termsofuse
INNER JOIN vehicle ON vehicle.TTC_TYP_ID = _termsofuse.TTC_TYP_ID
INNER JOIN part ON part.TTC_ART_ID = _termsofuse.TTC_ART_ID
INNER JOIN term_of_use_name ON term_of_use_name.Name = _termsofuse.TERM_OF_USE_NAME AND term_of_use_name.ID_Lang = 2
INNER JOIN term_of_use_value ON term_of_use_value.Value = _termsofuse.TERM_OF_USE_VALUE AND term_of_use_value.ID_Lang = 2
INTO OUTFILE 'termsofuse.csv'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

This query takes longer than 8 hours on my laptop (I have 4 GB of RAM).
I tried to see the explain of the SELECT part and it shows the following:
[image: Explain statement]

I do not understand where exactly is the bottleneck. I have exported a similar (about 95 Million records) query in less than 1h. Also breaking the results into multiple tables using `limit` does not seem to help much...
Please have a look and any additional info you require just tell me.
Thank you in advance.
**EDIT 15/01/2016**
Results of Explain Select
[image]

Comment: Right off the bat, the biggest gain would be to change the join on varchars to ints, figure out a better way to get at the data in the terms_of_use* tables. Or at the very least add indices for the join columns in the terms_of_use* tables if you can't join on ints.

Comment: I suspected that the index on (varchar, int) is the main problem. The thing is I can't think of a way to avoid this - the ID is autogenerated. The join columns are (Name, ID_Lang) and the index is already on them, I can't improve this, can I?

Comment: Ok, it seems that `distinct` without index is quite a problem. I am not sure how to solve this. Now on varchar fields: is it better to create a partial (prefixed) index on the varchar columns or create a new column to store an md5 value to use for indexing?

Answer (score 0):

Why have an `ID` when you have a perfectly good `UNIQUE` `INT` that could be the PK?

Seriously -- Having to reach through a secondary key slows things down.  If each lookup slows it down by a factor of 2, that could add up.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be about 70% of *available* RAM.

Let's see the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`; there may be more clues there.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size had been set to 1GB.

Comment: I will update my question with the explain select. You mean it would have been better to have the Name, ID_Lang as PK? The thing is later I would need to join on ID, ID_Lang. Take into account that the ID is *not* unique. Two entries on different languages should have the same (otherwise auto-generated) ID.